# Postgres hstore, how to query for arrays containing values?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, hstore

[All codes here are samples] I have the Book model with the info field as hstore.

```
class Book < ActiveRecord::Base
  serialize :info, ActiveRecord::Coders::NestedHstore
end
```

and the info field is filled like this:

```
info: {"tags" => ["tag one", "tag two"]}
```

I need a query that I can find the books that contains the tag "tag one". How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Is this useful https://viget.com/extend/searching-serialized-fields-in-rails-using-postgres-arrays?

Comment: No :( It is not using hstore like this.

Answer (score 1):

You might not want to use a a `hstore` column here at all. Since `hstore` stores the values as plain text you need to do something like:

```
Book.where("WHERE info->'tags' LIKE '%?%'", "bestseller");
```

Seems like a decent idea until you realize that you are doing a full text search on a comma delimited string.

Instead you might want to use a `tags` table and a `book_tags` join table the good old way.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, realizing that, seems like not a very good way. Are you aware of more optimized ways of doing such query? The book and tags were just examples, both the key and possible values are dynamic.

Comment: If my array can contain 'any', 'anyone' and I search for any, in this way I would get records that can have 'anyone' but not 'any'.

Comment: Not really, I think its more an issue of proper database design - `hstore` is great for key/value data but it does not automatically turn Postgres into Mongodb. If you are shoving serialized data into a hstore than you should most likely be using a relation instead.

Comment: "If my array can contain 'any', 'anyone' and I search for any, in this way I would get records that can have 'anyone' but not 'any'." - yeah that why its a really bad idea. You could use a regexp but its going to be even slower.

Comment: Or use a JSON column instead as it actually supports nested scalars.

Comment: Changing it to a json column is an option. Does json columns have operators to support this type of query?

Comment: Maybe, I haven't tried it. http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/functions-json.html